# Can I set a variable in the build time before the installation process in Install4j?

Tags: install4j

For each installation I would like to introduce the current version on the welcome screen. For that, I create a "*Read a properties file*" action which reads my application *manifest.properties* which exists under the distribution tree. A step later I have a "Run script" action which extracts the properties I need for the version and set it into installer variables.

My problem is that when trying to install the installer on a clean computer it throws an error since it has no distribution tree nor the *manifest.properties*.

Is there any elegant way to set the variables before the installation process begins, like in the build time for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of your application is configured on the "General Settings->Application Info" step. You can use it in all text properties with this syntax:

```
${compiler:sys.version}
```

Comment: This is good but not exactly what I need. I don't want to configure and maintain the application version manauly in the "Application Info", for this I have the "manifest.properties" file on my application. is there any other similar solution I can use similar what I mentioned above?

Comment: You can set the version externally from your build tool, see https://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/cli/options.html For the command line compiler it's the `--release` flag, ant, gradle and maven integrations have similar properties.

Comment: I understand how it works but not sure how exactly since if I'm running the installer from the command line (jenkins in my case) so it won't running it through thr GUI. The application version is shown on the welcome screen, so how it works if I'm using -r STRING or --release=STRING?

Comment: Passing `-release=STRING` on the command line to `bin/install4jc` replaces the value that you have entered in the GUI with `STRING`. So you enter some placeholder in the GUI, like 1.0 and pass the actual value on the command line.

Comment: Thanks, that work.
So now I'm saving the application version into a variable and it work:
C:\Progra~1\install4j6\bin\install4jc.exe -r %app_version%

Why when I'm trying to concat a string to it - for example:
C:\Progra~1\install4j6\bin\install4jc.exe -r Beta %app_version% - I'm getting the error:
install4j: too many arguments?

Comment: You would have to quote it as -r "Beta %app_version%"